# My session and middleware is not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

Actually I wanted that my application will go to admin_panel.blade.php only if the user login. I don't want to go there directly. So I implemented middleware and session but it's not working because if I directly goes to 'admin_panel' then it does not restrict me. Without or with using login information it grants me to go to admin_panel.

Kindly solve my issue.

**Web.php**

```
Route::get('/admin_log', function () {
    return view('Admin.admin_login');
});
Route::group(['middleware'=>'session_auth'],function(){
    Route::get('/admin_panel','LoginController@admin_panel');
```

**LoginController**

```
public function admin_panel(){
        return view('Admin.admin_panel');
    }
    public function admin_login(Request $req){
        $login=AdminLogin::first();

        if ($login->Admin_Name==$req->admin_name && $login->Admin_Password==$req->admin_password ){
            $req->session()->put('session_name',$req->admin_name);

            return redirect('admin_panel');

        }

        else{
            return redirect('admin_log')->with('error','Invalid UserName or Password!');
        }


    }
```

**Middleware**

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(is_null($request->session()->get('session_name'))){
            return redirect('/admin_log');
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
```

Comment: Could you show the kernal.php code

Comment: `protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'session_auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\session_auth::class,
    ];`

Comment: last one i used that is **session_auth**

Comment: Did you try to change session_auth file name and class name to 'SessionAuth'